# Launch web browser on Gnome startup

Tags: gnome, session

I have come to find out that there are many ways to run scripts on user log in

In a terminal I can run this command: `iceweasel -private bgp.he.net`

And that'll do exactly what I want

But how would I do that automatically after I log in?

It's so confusing because every thing I read after googling requires using a couple different commands... there's got to be a simpler way

I'm sure some one is going to suggest using `/etc/init.d` but is that really necessary? What does it take for a `.sh` file to be auto ran in `init.d`? Does just being in that directory make it run or do you need to register it somehow?

The reason I think `init.d` isn't for the job is because that starts boot time stuff, and my question is regarding user login, so there has to be a user-specific way to run scripts on login.

I am using Gnome on Kali Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `init.d` service is not really meant for running GUI tools for the user's desktop. It's typically used to start services.

So instead I would attack the problem in a slightly different way using one of the methods discussed below. In particular I typically use *the alternative approach*.

Usually you put X related items that you'd like to run in the context of the user (you) in one of these files:

- $HOME/.xsession
- $HOME/.xinitrc
- For GNOME desktops you can put commands in $HOME/.gnomerc
- For KDE you put commands in $HOME/.kde/Autostart

#### Alternative Approach

Try adding the app as a startup program under the "Startup Application" dialog.

**Step #1**

Create a shell script, `iceweasel.bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash
iceweasel -private bgp.he.net
```

**Step #2**

Add a startup task to run the shell script.

Open the application *Startup Applications*, under *System →  Preferences*

[image: ss of dialog #1]

Then click the *Add* button

[image: ss of add dialog]

Once you're done OK & Close the dialogs and to test it out logout and log back in.

#### References

- [Starting Your X Session: .xinitrc and .xsession](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/workshops/cool_unix/xinitrc.html)

Comment: xsession and xinitrc were tingling in my brain but idk how to use them yet. and the reason i didn't mention anything of it in the post is because those files don't exist. can i just create it an put my commands in them?

Comment: @noname - yes, just create them to try.

Comment: well i put my command in a blank .xsession and i logged out logged back in and the web browser opened and it's displaying the website (internet works) but literally the only thing is the web browser... no window manager, no menu with close button or minimize window

Comment: @noname - I generally use the alternative approach. You can refer to the references link for any additional info on the `.xsession` file but I don't typically use that method.

Comment: im getting an access forbidden trying to go there

Comment: @noname - in the shell script you can put a command such as `sleep 10` before the iceweasel cmd. I suspect your network connection is not fully up, prior to iceweasel trying to access the internet.

Comment: on the linux machine the internet works just fine, but im gonna have to reinstall the os bcus i cannot do anything after logging in but go to websites due to no window manager. i'm trying to access the website you posted on a different windows machine that im typing on right now. access forbidden...

Comment: @noname - did you remove the `.xsession` file?

Comment: i cant. i dont know how to launch anything. the only window is iceweasel

Comment: @noname - if you Ctrl+Alt+F2 you can drop to a console window and login. From there do a `rm .xsession` to remove the file. From there you can reboot or Ctrl+Alt+F1 or Ctrl+Alt+F7 to get back to your X Windows GUI.

Comment: wow thanks, now i learned a few things. hopefully one day im a linux master